# Visa Type for an internship in UK

Tags: visas, uk, working-visas

I am a student and I have an unpaid internship of four months in the United Kingdom and my parents will support me during my stay.
I don't have a certificate of sponsorship I only have the contract.
I tried applying for Tier 5 Temporary Worker-Government Authorised exchange but the certificate of sponsorship is necessary for that type of Visa.
So Can I apply for a Standard Visitor Visa?

Comment: @Newton Have you asked the organisation where you’ll be doing the internship for assistance? I’d expect them to be able to help given that they’ve offered you the opportunity

Comment: I did, they said that they only give the acceptance letter.

Comment: This fits better at our sister site [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com) since it's contemplating longer-term study or residency, not just tourism or business travel.

Comment: @Newton This states that interns are not allowed to enter on a visitor visa https://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=f794c5b2-b008-4d6a-84ee-ac36c7accc7e It also seems that a Certificate of Sponsorship should be given.

Comment: can i replace the certificate of sponsorship with the contract? it has my personal details and the hours of work and everything.

Comment: @Traveller I just edited the question I am not the op